# How to prevent content from hiding under the iOS Safari UI

Tags: css, ios, safari, viewport

I'm trying to create a single page application for the web and so far it's been going well.
Unfortunately, when testing it on an iPhone I realized that part of my website's contents are hidden underneath the navigation bar of the browser (Safari). Normally, when scrolling down on a website that UI element disappears and makes way for the content under it to show properly and use the screen space efficiently, but since my site has scrolling disabled (since I'm trying to make a single screen UI) part of it ends down there.

I've noticed this only affects Safari, and my app works perfectly on other browsers, even on mobile.

So far, to solve this issue I've tried to use environment variables on CSS like this:
`height: calc(100vh - env(safe-area-inset-bottom))`

But it didn't seem to make any difference.
So what I'm asking for is: is there any way to prevent this from happening, perhaps loading the website on fullscreen already hiding the browser's UI?

For context, here is the problem:

### Current state:

[image: Current state]

### The part of the page that gets hidden (enabled scrolling):

[image: The part of the page that gets hidden (enabled scrolling)]

### Desired result:

[image: What I want to accomplish]

(Also, I've noticed that a Wordle clone I regularly play ([term.ooo](https://term.ooo)) has managed to pull off what I wanted to do, so there's got to be a way but I haven't figured it out by analyzing their CSS '-')

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to do something like this :

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;  /* standard definition (as fallback) */
    height: 100dvh; /* dynamic vh will make the trick on iOS */
}
```